# Minimum Android OS versions for WebP images support

Tags: android, api, image-processing, webp, android-4.1-jelly-bean

Have to provide the WebP images through API based on Android Os version. So Can you please provide the list of Low end Android OS versions supporting WebP images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#image-formats), WebP was supported starting in Android 4.0. However:

- Transparency support was only added in Android 4.2.1
- Lossless compression support is new to Android 10